# UIButton scaled with core animation doesn't change hit area

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, uibutton

I have a uibutton that I animate to scale down.
But the hit area doesn't scale down with it and stays at its orignal size.

my code:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

float widthScale = size.width / view.frame.size.width;
float heightScale = size.height / view.frame.size.height;

animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(widthScale, heightScale, 1.0)];

CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:animation];
animGroup.duration = 0.5;
animGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[view.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];
```

The button has a image that i set with setImage:forState:
I give the button a frame and i put the autoresizeSubviews to YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAAnimation` scales/etc. the view's underlying layer; the view itself occupies the same bounds. To modify the view itself, try using a `UIView` animation block and modifying the view's transform property.

Comment: pitty that you cannot use CAAnimation for that.

Comment: `CAAnimation` is only meant for animating other Core Animation objects. It's by design.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old discussion but I just met a similar situation and the question doesn't seem to be really answered...

Layers do not respond to touches directly (touches delegate is only the UIView's controller but not its underlaying CALayer). A possible solution to fix the hit area after animating the layer is to modify the *view.frame* property (of the backing view) adapting its size and origin explicitly/"manually" to the final (expected) size of the animated layer.

The transformed *view.frame* will allow again response to touches in a correct area without affecting the animated CALayer shape. In other words, the CALayer object and the frame property of the UIView seem untied.